# web2py after user login show elements in views

Tags: javascript, authentication, web2py

I am workign with web2py and I have a div class = "navbar" id="navbar">{{='auth' in globals() and auth.navbar(separators=(' ',' | ',''))}}  element for user login and registration.

Everything works ok.

After a user logs in I would like to show him some elements in view that are hidden before that.

I guess I do that using java script but I wanna know what to get or collect with its funciton so I can use it as a marker for showing hidden elements

thank you

Comment: Are these elements that a non-logged in user should not be allowed to access? If so, you should not merely show/hide them via Javascript, as in that case, a knowledgeable user could just view the page source to see the data.

Comment: So you recomend to do a newview file and a redirect to that view after login? I tried but the redirect auth.settings.login_next=URL(r=request,c='school_postlogin',f='index') does not work

Comment: auth.settings.login_next is just a default in case the user starts at the login page. Using the auth.navbar "login" link to get to the login page results in the user getting redirected back to the page they were on before login (i.e., the referring page). If you don't want that behavior, do `auth.navbar(..., referrer_actions=[...])`, where referrer_actions is a list of actions that should redirect back to the referring page (just make sure you exclude "login" from that list).